# Interactive ImageView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have been researching for a while, and I have found a lot of questions and answers on how to use a gesture recognizer on a UIImageView in iOS to make the image interactive. However, I am hoping to make an interactive image that reacts differently depending on the part of the image that is tapped (think of an interactive map or an interactive image of the human body).

I am still in the planning phase, but I cannot think of a way to do this. My first idea was to use UIButtons over the image, but I cannot think of a way to make the constraints allow the buttons to remain stationary over the image for different devices. I am looking for ideas, either on another way of doing this, or a way to make the constraints work.

Comment: Questions asking for opinions / ideas are generally considerer off-topic in the current rules of Stack Overflow. Instead, do a trial implementation and bring it here  if yuo get any error or strange behavior.

Comment: It takes a lot of work. I think a CoreML framework will be helpful for you